# jQuery Performance Issue

Tags: jquery, algorithm, performance

I have a performance issue when I use this code but more than 1000 `<tr>` rows

The idea is that I have tags `<tr>` that inside have td with text and I'm trying to hide and show if text contains or not. The code works, but with more than 1000 `<tr>` with info I have a lot of delay. There is some way to make it faster?
This code is called when text change, so called less than keypress (the original way that I wanted)

```
var grilla = $(control).parent().parent().next().next();
  var texto = $.trim($(control).val());


    if(texto.length < 2){
        grilla.children().children().children().children('tr').show(200);
        return false;
    }

    var renglones = grilla.children().children().children().children("tr");
    if($(renglones).children('td:first').children().is('[type=text]')){
        console.info('busca en inputs');
            buscarGrillaInputs(renglones,texto);
            return false;
    }

    $.each( renglones, function() {
        if (!$(this).children('td').is(':contains('+texto.toLowerCase()+')') && !$(this).children('td').is(':contains('+texto.toUpperCase()+')')){
            $(this).hide(200);
        }
        else{
            $(this).show(200);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Have  you attempted to run a profile in Chrome console? Another question too: does your td cell only include text, or other markup?

Comment: sometimes could be div with input type text inside the td, that would be the major case.  Why the question about the console?? i did not understand

Comment: When you have performance problems, sometimes using the Profiles functionality can help you identify which part of your code is causing the issue, allowing you to focus your efforts on fixing the most important area.

Comment: Also, you might try changing the is(':contains') stuff to !$(this).children('td').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(lc_texto) >= 0 (where you have already set var lc_texto = texto.toLowerCase() once before the loop)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the contains selector at one point and found that the performance was very slow. I have better luck with $.filter

Also the .show(200) will hurt you. Where there are such a large number of entries to run through just run .show() same with .hide()

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/e7yvrta1/

```
$('#search').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    var phrase = this.value;
    $('tr').hide();
    $('table input').filter(function () {
        return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(phrase) != -1;
    }).closest('tr').show();

});
```